# C++ UNIX Help - simple TCP server socket connection

Tags: c++, linux, unix, tcp

I am a student writing a C++ code using UNIX system calls to perform simple server <-> client requests from the Terminal. The user (me) input in the port for both programs (Server and Client) in the Terminal to establish a connection, the goal is for the Server to send back to the Client the contents of what the Client program input in.

I.e:

Terminal 1:
./server 9000

Terminal 2:
./client localhost 9000 ~

Will show a list of all directories and files in Home.

Or
Terminal 2: ./client localhost 9000 test.txt

Will read contents from the test.txt file and write it onto the Client's terminal.

As of now, only folders work. Whenever I try a file instead, it prints a blank line. This is my code for the process function:

```
void processClientRequest(int connSock)
{
    int received;
    char path[1024], buffer[1024];
    
    // Read from the client
    if((received = read(connSock, path, sizeof(path))) < 0)
    { perror("receive"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }
    
    // Check if it is a directory or a file
        struct stat s;
        if(stat(path,&s) == 0 )
        {
            // It is a directory
            if(s.st_mode & S_IFDIR)
            {
                DIR *dirp = opendir(path);
                if (dirp == 0)
                {
                    // Tell client they gave the inappropriate input
                    // Duplicate socket descriptor into error output
                    // Then print it to client's end with perror to
                    // Give more in-depth details of the error to user
                    close(2);
                    dup(connSock);
                    perror(path);
                    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
                }
            
                struct dirent *dirEntry;
                while((dirEntry = readdir(dirp)) != NULL)
                {
                    // If statement to hides all files/folders that start with a dot
                    // Which are hidden files/folders
                    if(dirEntry->d_name[0] != '.')
                    {
                        strcpy(buffer, dirEntry->d_name);
                        strcat(buffer, "\n");
                        if(write(connSock, buffer, strlen(buffer)) < 0)
                        { perror("write"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }
                    }
                }
                closedir(dirp);
                close(connSock);
                exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);         
            }
            // It is a file
            else if(s.st_mode & S_IFREG)
            {
                int fd = open(path, O_RDONLY);
                if(fd < 0) { perror("open"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }
                read(fd, buffer, strlen(buffer));
                strcat(buffer, "\n");
                if(write(connSock, buffer, strlen(buffer)) < 0)
                { perror("write"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }
                close(fd);
            }
            // Not a file or directory
            else
            {
                cout << "It is neither a file nor directory!" << endl;
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
        }
    
        else
        {
            // Same explanation as line 95 - 98
            close(2);
            dup(connSock);
            perror("stat");
            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
        }
    close(connSock);
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

As a side question, how do I get it to accept/recognize a codeword before executing the process as well as the double quotes? As of now I can only use *./client ... pathname/"name with spaces"* ; if I use *./client ... "pathname/name with spaces"* it displays a *stat: no such file or directory* error.
For example:

./client localhost 4000 "**GET** pathname/filename"

Comment: What is your proof that: 1) the `read()` will receive everything that the client sent to it (`read()` from a socket gives you no guarantees, whatsoever, that it will read everything that the other side sent, it may return only the 1st byte on the 1st call to `read()`, and it must be called again to `read()` the rest of what the client sent), and 2) that the string passed to `stat()` is `'\0'` terminated, like all C-style strings must be?

Comment: Until you know all of the rules, there are no simple TCP socket connections. Rule 1: Never ignore the return codes. They are all important and several of them mean different things depending on the value. For example if `read` returns a negative number, that's an error. You can look it up with `perror` if interested. A return of 0 means polite disconnection. A positive number is the number of bytes you'll find in the buffer you provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You problem is here:

```
else if(s.st_mode & S_IFREG)
{
    int fd = open(path, O_RDONLY);
    if(fd < 0) { perror("open"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }
    read(fd, buffer, strlen(buffer)); << Change strlen(buffer)
    strcat(buffer, "\n");
    if(write(connSock, buffer, strlen(buffer)) < 0)
    { perror("write"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }
    close(fd);
}
```

`strlen(buffer)` can be any value, because you are initializing buffer to 1024 bytes. The memory area is possibly being filled full of zeroes. `strlen(buffer)` would then be returning 0, because the first character is a null byte. Nothing is being written into the buffer because `read` will end up writing zero bytes.

Comment: This is just one many bugs in the shown code, and it is likely that it doesn't even get to this point, as a result of the other bugs.

Comment: That's true. There are a lot of bugs in the code. This was the first one I could find.

Comment: Thank you for discerning it. I am still new at this.